# ThreadLocal JPA EntityManager in DAO

Tags: jpa, dao, entitymanager, thread-local

In my `DAO` classes I have a reference to an `EntityManager`. I want to make the acces to the `EntityManager` thread-safe by using `ThreadLocal`.

So far my attempts have only resulted in `NullPointerException`s, and I can't seem to find a decent example.

Can someone provide me with an example or point me in the right direction?

**update**: I've tried BalusC's suggestion, but when I acces the DAO through JSF and the JAX-RS webservice at the same time, I'm still getting errors:

```
 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity
 java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement
```

I'm using C3P0, so I don't know why a closed connection is a problem.

**update2**:  BalusC's last comment seemed to have solved my problem: `At least, you should not have a single instance of the DAO class shared throughout the application. Create a new one on every request.`

Comment: Is this for a Java EE web application? If so, why don't you use EJBs wherein you inject `EntityManager` by `@PersistenceContext`? This way all threadsafety and transactional concerns will completely disappear.

Comment: It's for a JSF application + REST Webservice. Using `@PersistenceContext` resulted in `NullPointerException`s

Comment: It can only be used in beans running in a transaction, e.g. `@Stateless` EJB, or a JSF `@ManagedBean`. In all other cases such as a "plain vanilla" DAO nothing will be injected and hence it remains `null`.

Comment: Thanks, got it working with `@ManagedBean`. Is there an annotation for transactions too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I want to make the acces to the `EntityManager` thread-safe by using `ThreadLocal`.*

Don't do that. Let the container worry about this. I'd make your DAOs a [`@Stateless`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html) EJB and use [`@PersistenceContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) to inject the [`EntityManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html). E.g.

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public User find(Long id) {
        return em.find(User.class, id);
    }

    // ...
}
```

To inject it in your JSF managed beans or JAX-RS services, just use [`@EJB`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html):

```
@EJB
private UserService userService;
```

To control the transaction level, use [`@TransactionAttribute`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) annotation (which defaults to [`TransactionAttributeType#REQUIRED`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRED)).

Comment: I've added the jar containing the annotations, but I'm still getting `TransactionRequiredException` although the methods are marked with `@TransactionAttribute`

Comment: So you did not turn your DAOs into EJBs? You need to begin and commit the transactions manually then.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I'm still suspecting a threading problem (original post updated).

Comment: This suggests that the same DAO instance is been shared between JSF and JAX-RS. Each should get their own instance. Or, better, make it an EJB. Then you don't worry about threadsafety and transactional concerns.

Comment: Making it EJB results in a javax.naming.namenotfoundexception name MANAGED_BEAN_NAME is not bound in this context

Comment: Phew. First, what container are you using? Tomcat or something which doesn't support EJB/JPA out the box? What were you using to add/configure the EJB/JPA capabilities?

Comment: Tomcat 7, I've added hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar and ejb-3.0.jar .

Comment: Right, that explains it. Something is clearly messed up in configuration. Sorry, I don't have hands-on experience with manually enriching Tomcat with EJB/JPA support, so I can't be of assistance. All I can do is to suggest you to take a look at Glassfish Web Profile. All will "just" work out the box without much fiddle. Otherwise, well, maybe just drop the EJB idea. At least, you should not have a single instance of the DAO class shared throughout the application. Create a new one on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you tring to CDI inject your EntityManger when you're not in an EJB app server? Just Grab a hold of your EntityManagerFactory using javax.persistence.Persistence and the name of your persistence unit, then with the EMF get a hold of your EntityManager(s) like in a servelet and what not. Use data base transaction locks to ensure consistem parallel access to the db, don't go around making EntityManager "thread" safe in java code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `Use data base transaction locks`?

Comment: This is something that can't be discussed in a comment forum. Look at your entityManager methods, some of them are overloaded to take a LockType as parameter. Also read this: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html